# How can i increase the button width dynamically depends on the text size in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, width, dynamic

I have created 10 buttons programmatically and set the titles in the button. Now i want to increase the button frame size dynamically,its depends on the text.

I given some conditions and set the frame size. but how can i set the exact frame size depends on the text(get the text dynamically).

Here my sample code is,

```
     float x=0, y=0, w, h=20;

    for(int i = 100; i < 110; i++)
     {
         btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];

         UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Round_Rect4.png"];

        [btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        titleString = [titleArray objectAtIndex:i-100];  // get button title

        if([titleString length] <= 5)
        {
            w = 50;
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); 

            x = x + 70;
        }

        if (([titleString length] >= 6) && ([titleString length] <=10))
       {
             w = 70;

             btn.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); 

             x = x + 90;
       } 

       if(([titleString length] >= 11) && ([titleString length] <=15))
       {
             w = 105;
             btn.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); 

             x = x + 120;

       }

       if([titleString length] >= 16)
       {
             w = 120;
             btn.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); 

             x = x + 140;

       }

        [btn setTitle:titleString forState: UIControlStateNormal];

        [btn setTag:i];

        [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

}

see the example image,

[image-2 http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b6e0f234dc.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b6e0f234dc.png)
 [image-1 http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6b3daab12f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6b3daab12f.png)

So is this possible to set the exact button frame size which depends on the text?, plz guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer and my working code is,

```
        float x=0;

        for(int i = 100; i < 110; i++)
         {
             btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];

             UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Round_Rect4.png"];

            [btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];

            titleString = [titleArray objectAtIndex:i-100];  // get button title

           CGSize fontSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];

            CGRect currentFrame = btn.frame;

            CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(x, currentFrame.origin.y, fontSize.width + 22.0, fontSize.height + 12.0);

           [btn setFrame:buttonFrame];

            x = x + fontSize.width + 35.0;

            [btn setTitle:titleString forState: UIControlStateNormal];

            [btn setTag:i];

            [self.view addSubview:btn];

}
```

Comment: Why not `[titleString sizeWithFont:btn.font]`?

Comment: If i used [titleString sizeWithFont:btn.font] this code and the warning is displayed.(Font is deprecated).

Comment: @Pugal use `[titleString sizeWithFont:[btn titleLabel].font]` instead, to avoid warning.

Answer (score 14):

```
[btn sizeToFit]
```

Comment: Heehee. But that doesnt really take in account that the background image has rounded corners.

Comment: No; you have to do that yourself — something like `btn.contentEdgeInsets = (UIEdgeInsets){.left=8,.right=8}`

Answer (score 3):

Very simple solution:

```
TestButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);
[TestButton sizeToFit];
float width  =   TestButton.frame.size.width + 20;
TestButton.frame = CGRectMake(TestButton.frame.origin.x, TestButton.frame.origin.y, width, 40);
```

Comment: This made me realize I needed to be resetting the entire frame (as opposed to trying to update the existing frame's width value, which is readonly). Thx.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. saved my time. Bingo! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Copy an pasted from Apples Bubble Level source code.

This is the line you want

```
UIImage *newImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];
```

full code here

```
- (UIButton *)buttonWithTitle:(NSString *)title target:(id)target selector:(SEL)inSelector frame:(CGRect)frame image:(UIImage*)image {
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIImage *newImage = [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:target action:inSelector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = YES;
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];   // in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
    [button autorelease];
    return button;
}
```