# Customize the UIButton resize according to text length and place UILabel after that

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sizewithfont

I have used following code and got error as below i.e less space in small text and more space long text

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];

    UIButton *BtnBreadcrumb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [BtnBreadcrumb addTarget:self action:@selector(selectBtnBreadcrumb:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [BtnBreadcrumb setTitle:selectedDepartment forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    BtnBreadcrumb.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    BtnBreadcrumb.tintColor=ThemeColor;
    CGSize stringsize = [selectedDepartment sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
    BtnBreadcrumb.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, stringsize.width, 40);
    [view addSubview:BtnBreadcrumb];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stringsize.width, 5, 200, 40)];
    //[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ %@",selectedCategory];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    label.textColor = TextColor;
     [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.933f green:0.933f blue:0.933f alpha:1.00f]];
    return view;
}
```

[image]
[image]

I have study following links

[iOS: UIButton resize according to text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135032/ios-uibutton-resize-according-to-text-length)

[How can i increase the button width dynamically depends on the text size in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302943/how-can-i-increase-the-button-width-dynamically-depends-on-the-text-size-in-ipho)
[Replacement for deprecated -sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903304/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfontconstrainedtosizelinebreakmode-in-ios)
[Replacement for deprecated sizeWithFont: in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897896/replacement-for-deprecated-sizewithfont-in-ios-7)

[IOS 7 sizeWithFont Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591621/ios-7-sizewithfont-deprecated)

Comment: @nishalhada are you talking about `Pet/Pet Accessories` and `Canned & Jarred Food       / Canned Fruit & Vegetables`?

Comment: yes dude you are right

Comment: you need to assign the size of the button font     **[BtnBreadcrumb.titleLabel setFont: [BtnBreadcrumb.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:17]];**

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
CGSize size1 = [strkeyword1Partner1 sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_MYriad_REGULAR size:14.0f]}];

// Values are fractional -- you should take the ceilf to get equivalent values

CGSize adjustedSize1= CGSizeMake(ceilf(size1.width), ceilf(size1.height));

[btnKewword1 setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-(adjustedSize1.width +14), btnKewword.frame.origin.y, adjustedSize1.width+5, 20)];
```

Comment: i have up vote for ur efforts hopes to get same on my questions too

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 0);
    btn.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [btn setTitle:@"dsgdfgdfsdsfgdfsgdfsgdfsgdfgdfgfkdsfgdsgdksfgkdskgf" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: can you check the question once again please

Comment: i have up vote for ur efforts hopes to get same on my questions too

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code I add the size of the UIButton.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];

    UIButton *BtnBreadcrumb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [BtnBreadcrumb addTarget:self action:@selector(selectBtnBreadcrumb:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [BtnBreadcrumb.titleLabel setFont: [BtnBreadcrumb.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:17]];

    [BtnBreadcrumb setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    BtnBreadcrumb.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    BtnBreadcrumb.tintColor=ThemeColor;
    CGSize stringsize = [selectedDepartment sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
    BtnBreadcrumb.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, stringsize.width, 40);
    [view addSubview:BtnBreadcrumb];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(stringsize.width, 5, 200, 40)];
    //[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ %@",selectedCategory];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    label.textColor = TextColor;
    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.933f green:0.933f blue:0.933f alpha:1.00f]];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: adding  **[BtnBreadcrumb.titleLabel setFont: [BtnBreadcrumb.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:17]];**

Comment: i have up vote for ur efforts hopes to get same on my questions too